# When Spider-man revealed his identity during Civil War, why did Osborn say he "broke the rules"?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

Specifically, **this moment** ([Civil War, Front Line #2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_War:_Front_Line))  when he revealed his identity to the press and started to take questions.

What makes this puzzling is that we see Norman get furious for a few panels (as do others like [JJJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Jonah_Jameson)) but there's no follow-up in this issue (or in the series) that explains why he said this (as far as I can tell!)

[image]
[image]

Trying to dig through multiple issues of [ASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Spider-Man) and the canon in general to figure out what arrangement or rules did Norman think he had with Peter back when their conflict was more frequent?

I doubt the former Green Goblin meant "super-powered costumed folk don't ever reveal their secret identity" (his was known far and wide at this time, anyhow).

So was there some moment during their bitter history together where Norman assumed **some** sort of pact or arrangement?

Comment: In unfamiliar with it but one reading suggests this refers to the original scene where Gwen died. I think spidey chose Gwen, this breaking the rules.  Regardless,  I'm paging @Thaddeus.

Comment: Not sure that is true.  By your reasoning, Peter chose Gwen ages ago; nothing to trigger a reaction from Normie like this in the present.

Comment: Except Spidey blaming him publicly on TV....

Comment: civil war spoilers in title :(

Comment: Wondering what the statute of limitations is for spoilers? This question is about the 2006-2007 comic series  (created back in a time free of disney and avengers blockbuster hype).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Green Goblin has, for a very long time, known Spider-Man's secret identity. He has been playing a "game" with Peter ever since: Peter knows that Norman could expose him at any point, and could go after his friends and family; and Norman knows that Peter always managed to outsmart or outwit him and thwart his plans.

Thus, Norman's "game" is simply that "You let me escape and I keep your secret."

This game is, of course, mostly in Obsorn's head, but it's very real to him. Any time he thinks Peter is breaking the rules, he reacts negatively. For example, at one point, Peter manages to have Osborn arrested and put into a high-security prison. He responds by implementing a failsafe plan involving kidnapping Aunt May to get back at Peter.

[image]

When Peter revealed his identity to the world, he took away Norman's leverage against him. He ended the game prematurely -- he "broke the rules".

Comment: Much better than my answer in my opinion.

Comment: Revisiting this answer and I notice a parallel to Hans Landa (Inglorious Basterds)'s jovial/banter behavior to Aldo's men (where he knew they were pretending to be Italians) vs. his murdering fury over Hammersmark's inability to "stay within the game".

Answer (score 7):

I do not have any good evidence to back this up, but my feeling is that Osborn is claiming that Peter "broke the rules" because he shared their feud with others. In Osborn's mind, this is personal, man-to-man. Of course, the Green Goblin has regularly brought in other foes to fight Spider-man, but he's also insane, so it makes perfect sense to him that his private fight with Spider-man allows him to bring in reinforcements while Peter must fight alone.

Alternately, his beef is over calling out Osborn as Osborn rather than as the Goblin. All these years that the Goblin has been withholding Parker's identity wasted...